# What should be the characterisitc dimension for angled entry of cylinder in water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, flow, solid-mechanics

I am working on problem for angled entry of cylindrical object in water (30 degrees and 60 degrees), for that I need to calculate the characteristic dimension of the cylinder to calculate the impact Reynolds number. I not getting the idea about this, because for standard problem like flow past circular cylinder of infinite length, it is taken as diameter. So what should be the variation in charateristic dimension as the angle for water entry changes

Comment: why would the characteristic dimension change rather than e.g. the characteristic speed at which the cylinder impacts the water?

Comment: I have confusion that whether i should take diameter or length as  characteristic dimension. Can you please clarify situation in this case?  @nluigi

Comment: I believe you already have the answer.  The characteristic dimension that changes, is the angle the cylinder makes with the water flow direction.  For "standard" flow, the angle is zero.  You now need to figure out what happens when the angle is changed (30, 60, etc.)

Comment: Ok let's be frank now, I am taking the charactristic dimension of cylindrical object to be : m=  (l*sin(a))+(d*cos(a)); where the 'l' is length of cylidrical object, 'd'  is diameter of object and 'a' is angle made by cylidrical object with water interface while impacting the water pool. This helps in keeping the characteristic dimension to be length for vertical entry and diameter as charateristic dimension for horizontal entry. I want to know whether this case taken is right or wrong? In both cases, please give some strong references for your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Using (a) as the angle the cylinder makes with the surface of the water, in the **vertical** position (a = 90 degrees), the length (l) should make **no contribution** (only (d)), and in the **horizontal** position (a = 0 degr.), the diameter (d) should make **no contribution** (only (l)).  This means that the correct formula should be m = (lcos(a) + dsin(a)).

The characteristic dimension for vertical entry has to be the diameter (d), and for horizontal entry has to be the length (l).

For vertical entry  a = 90 degr., therefore m = d
For horizontal entry a = 0 degr., therefore m = l

Comment: Sir, that is ok. But I need some references, that i going wrong or right with this kind of formulations. Apart from that the formula i have written above based upon the flow past a horzontal cylinder with 'd' is taken as characterisitc dimensions when it is positioned perpendicular to direction of flow. i.e. aligned horizontal while impacting the water pool, because at that time the flow will be perpendicular to alignement of cylindrical object.